# Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given *13*

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on a system for my school that lets the teachers post any notices they have for the day on the intranet. However I got this error when testing it out:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\wamp64\www\my-site\viewguestbook.php on line 23.

Here is the page's code:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="guestbook"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysqli_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysqli_query($sql);
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
```

Note: This is different to the other questions of this same name on the website as it's in a different circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of `mysqli_select_db()` is connection object. This is the syntax :

```
mysqli_select_db(connection,dbname);
```

Change your code to:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysqli_select_db($con,$db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
```

Add the connection object as first parameter in `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_fetch_array` functions too. Please refer this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp) for the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_db_select()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php) method requires two parameters

- connection object
- database name (that needs to be selected)

So, you should pass connection object to the `mysqli_db_select()`

```
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="test"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="guestbook"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select database.
    $connection = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
    mysqli_select_db($connection,$db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
    $result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
?>
```

Comment: `$result=mysqli_query($sql);` This line definitely show error message `mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
mysqli_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

to

```
 $connection =mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect server "); 
 mysqli_select_db($connection ,"$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

because `mysqli_select_db` needs the connection object as well.